# Exporting table from R to SQL Server

Tags: r, sql-server, export

I succeed to collect the data from https://www.gov.mb.ca/sd/fire/Fire-Situation/daily-firesituation.html into R. And I would like to export it now to SQL.

```
library('rvest')
url_Manitoba <- 'https://www.gov.mb.ca/sd/fire/Fire-Situation/daily- 
firesituation.html'
webpage_Manitoba <- read_html(url_Manitoba)

population <- webpage_Manitoba %>%
html_nodes("table") %>%
html_table(fill=TRUE)
population[[2]]
```

However I believe the table in R must have some changes to be exported to SQL. Like taking some of the data only. see in yellow what I need in the SQL table [image]

And to have it in a shape like
[image]

Comment: What flavor of SQL? This is possible through [DBI](https://dbi.r-dbi.org/reference/dbi-package)'s `dbWriteTable`, but there's varying configuration before it'll work.

Comment: SQL Server. What would be the varying config? I have much more knowledge in SQL that R, so I was thinking about exporting and then cleaning the data there.

Comment: [Here's some docs for connecting with ODBC](https://db.rstudio.com/databases/microsoft-sql-server/). It's all similar, but there are different packages for Postgres, SQLite, etc. You may also like [dplyr](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/), which is sort of SQL-like, or [sqldf](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf), which lets you run SQL against data frames.

Answer (score 1):

```
library("odbc")
library("DBI")

# Connect to SQL Server
con = dbConnect(odbc(),.connection_string = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=ipaddress;Uid=user;Pwd=password;")

# Write the table,is it doesn't exist it will be created
dbWriteTable(con, sql_table_name, polulation, append = TRUE, row.names = F)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. A few remarks I realized I havent been clear.

I didnt create the table yet in SQL and I actually don't know how to do it since currently what I extracted from the website in R does not look like a proper SQL table with one row/ one column per data. 

I was expecting to have to do some changes in R to be able to export it to SQL. I will add pictures in the question. Thanks!

Comment: R will create the table for you and insert the data, dont worry :)

Comment: Hi Daniel, what would the code look like when I wanted to add a table into a database which is in a SQL server? I think the code above would write at the root... right?   server root >> existing database >> table in database Id like to write

Comment: that code would work

Answer (score 0):

By writing the data to a CSV locally and then using a BULK INSERT (not readily available as a prebuilt function akin to sqlSave), the data can be written to the MS SQL Server very quickly.

```
toSQL = data.frame(...);
write.table(toSQL,"C:\\export\\filename.txt",quote=FALSE,sep=",",row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE,append=FALSE);
    sqlQuery(channel,"BULK
                INSERT Yada.dbo.yada
                FROM '\\\\<server-that-SQL-server-can-see>\\export\\filename.txt'
                WITH
                (
                FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
                ROWTERMINATOR = '\\n'
                )");
```

Or . . .

Since insert INTO is limited to 1000 rows, you can dbBulkCopy from rsqlserver package.

dbBulkCopy is a DBI extension that interfaces the Microsoft SQL Server popular command-line utility named bcp to quickly bulk copying large files into table. For example:

```
url = "Server=localhost;Database=TEST_RSQLSERVER;Trusted_Connection=True;"
conn <- dbConnect('SqlServer',url=url)
## I assume the table already exist
dbBulkCopy(conn,name='T_BULKCOPY',value=df,overwrite=TRUE)
dbDisconnect(conn)
```